# Right vertical line in textview

Tags: java, android, textview, border

How can I create a right vertical line within the textview box I want to add a vertical border line on the right of the textview

I tried this but it generate a horizontal line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item>
 <shape android:shape="line">
    <stroke android:width="5dp" android:color="#FFFF00" />
    <solid android:color="#00000000" />

    <padding android:right="25dp" />

</shape>
```

How can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a "vertical" View and a RelativeLayout?
    `<View android_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:background="#FFFF00" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text_view"
/>`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<TextView 
        android:id="@id/textview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/"stringvalue""/>
    <View 
        android:id="@id/verticalId"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"/>
```